# Big - O notation linear and binary search

Tags: big-o, binary-search

In terms of Big - O notation the linear search is a x^n, but what is the binary search? I am not 100% that the linear search is correct.

Comment: Why did you tag this as c++?  Are you talking about particular c++ functions?

Comment: Linear search is *O(N)*  and binary search is *O(log(N))*. This is rather basic. No idea where you got *O(x^n)* from, or what *x* is here. I don't find anything unclear about this question, just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Linear search means that you will have to iterate through the list of elements until you find the element that you were looking for.

For instance, if you have a list with elements `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]` and you are looking for 11 you will start by the first element, then the second element, and so on, which in this case will take 6 iterations.

Generally, we could say that in the worst case you will have to traverse the whole list; so it will take n iterations, where n is the number of elements on the list.

So we say that the linear search algorithm is `O(n)`.

In the case of binary search, you start on the middle element of the list:

- **Case 1:** the number we are searching is the same as the number on the middle element: we are done!
- **Case 2:** the number we are searching is smaller: we will only search the elements that precedes the middle element.
- **Case 3:** the number we are searching is bigger: we will only search on the subsequent elements.

In our example, the number we are searching is 11 and the middle element is 5; since 11 > 5, we will only search on the sublist of the elements bigger than 5, namely `[7, 9, 11]`.

Now, we will keep doing the same until we find the element that we are searching, in this case it takes only three iterations to get to the last element.

In general this approach takes `log(n)` iterations; therefore, the algorithm is `O(log(n))`.

Note that the latter only works for sorted lists.